# How to add and use Sqlite Load Extension in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, load

Is it possible to use the SQLite load extension in Android?

Comment: You can't, at least not directly.  The version that the Java classes all talk to is fixed.  You could take the C++ code that implements SQLite and add in the externsion and create your own API to talk to it, rather than using your built in classes, but I wouldn't suggest it.  Instead I'd look at what you need that extension for and look for alternate ways to implement that functionality.

Comment: @WISHY Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to